# Editing images with feh

Tags: command-line, image-manipulation, feh

According to the `feh` man page:

> `--edit`     Enable basic editing of files.  This makes rotation and mirroring (bound to "<", ">", "|", and "_" by default) change the underlying file and not just its displayed content.

So based on my understanding of this, I should be able to use, for example, `feh --edit "<" image.png` to rotate an image. But when I try this, I get the message

```
feh WARNING: < does not exist - skipping
```

And when I try `feh --edit < image.png`, it opens a different image.

Does anyone know how to use the editing features of feh?

Comment: I read that manual text as if interactively pressing those _keys_ while `feh` is showing the image would change the image on disk.

Comment: I think you need to interpret "bound to `<`" as "when you press the `<` key on the keyboard while interactively editing", not "as a parameter to the `--edit` option". I don't have feh handy, but the online man pages refer to %r for being able to rotate.

Comment: Using feh with `--edit` will make you edit the original file if rotating the file, making the change persistent.
If you just start feh without the `--edit` option, that will allow you to edit in a live mode, but without changing the file on disk.
"<", ">", "|", and "_" are what you can press to change the image when it is being displayed.

Comment: It seems that feh does not read user input from stdin so `echo '<' | feh --edit image.png` does not work. You might be able to send key presses to feh with xdotool.